# Finding files in a folder and comparing to a list(txt)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory, text-processing

I need to create batch that will look in a folder that contains a 1000+ files, the files that exist are based on key words "the key words are numbers", each file in the folder contains these keywords and in each file name the key words are indexed at 0-3 from left to right, so they are the first four characters. and i have them saved in a txt one per line. So in a nut shell i need to compare all the files in the folder to the txt file to see which files exist (based on the key words) which are list and if they do exist i want to delete them from the txt to have a list that does not contain any of the files that exist in the folder.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: You say: `need to create`.  So why not give it a try?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("file list.txt") do (
    if exist "%%~a" (echo del "%%~a") else (echo(%%~a)>>"file list.new"
)
```

If it looks good, remove the `echo` command before `del`.

Comment: You'll want a space between 'usebackq' and 'delims' in there. :-)

Comment: Huh.  I'm surprised (but not shocked - this is cmd we're talking about :-) ).  Still, I think you'd *want* a space for clarity...